# how to find controls in usercontrols and pass it to string builder

Tags: c#

i can iterate through the controls which are on panel by this two code

```
       Form4 fl = new Form4();
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
       {
           if (c is ComboBox)
           {
               ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)c;
               sb.Append(cb.Text);
               fl.comboBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
               fl.Show();
           }

       }
```

OR by this
        List lst = new List();
       void GetComboBoxValues()

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    {
      sb.Append(c.Text + "\r\n");
    }
   MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
     }
```

but i add a panel and on panel a usercontrol which contains a combobox and textbox how that can be possible to find controls and add to the string builder 
    so i thought iterating through usercontrol and finding the text and adding it to the string builder,is that possible?

Comment: Why not try for yourself first and see whether it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to the comment left for L.B's answer. Personally I believe L.B's answer is the easiest and requires the least amount of coding, the best thing is it will find all the controls of a specific type on a panel no matter how nested they are(imagine if you have a user control inside a user control).

Just copy the `FindControls` method from LB's answer to your solution as is and where you need to loop through the controls of the panel, do something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var comboBoxes = FindControls<ComboBox>(panel1).ToList();
var textBoxes = FindControls<TextBox>(panel1).ToList();

foreach (var comboBox in comboBoxes)
    sb.AppendLine(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

foreach (var textbox in textBoxes)
    sb.AppendLine(textbox.Text);

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

A simple example would be something like this, but be warned that it will not work if you have a case of a user control inside a user control, so I would strongly suggest going with LB's example:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (panel1.Controls[i].Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            //Iterate through the controls in the user control
            foreach(Control c in panel1.Controls[i].Controls)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Handle the controls with no children
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this recursive method to find the controls

```
var combos = FindControls<ComboBox>(panel1).ToList();
```

or

```
var text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                       FindControls<ComboBox>(this).Select(c => c.Text));
```

---

```
IEnumerable<T> FindControls<T>(Control ctrl) where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(T)) yield return (T)c;
        foreach (var subC in FindControls<T>(c))
            yield return subC;
    }
}
```

**-----------------EDIT------------------**

> ***can you suggest easiest method***

```
List<ComboBox> combos = new List<ComboBox>();
FindComboBoxes(this,combos);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var combo in combos)
{
    sb.AppendLine(combo.Text);
}
```

---

```
void FindComboBoxes(Control parent,List<ComboBox> fillThis) 
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)) fillThis.Add((ComboBox)c);
        FindComboBoxes(c, fillThis);
    }
}
```

Comment: mine is easy. can you suggest easiest method, because i am a newbie to coding

Comment: @shariq_khan I updated the answer, but I don't think I can make it more easier.